# AWS Workspace with low bandwith

Tags: amazon-workspaces

I have a scenario of using AWS Workspace with low bandwidth. Is there any way to use aws workspace with low bandwidth? I'm getting "Your Network Connection is Unhealthy" though I had bandwidth of 100 MBPS download capability.

Any suggestions on this would be immensely helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From: [Amazon WorkSpaces Client Network Requirements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/workspaces-network-requirements.html)

> The client device must have a broadband internet connection. We
> recommend planning for **a minimum of 1 Mbps** per simultaneous user
> watching a 480p video window. Depending on your user-quality
> requirements for video resolution, more bandwidth might be required.

> For the best performance for PCoIP, the round trip time (RTT) from the
> client's network to the Region that the WorkSpaces are in should be
> less than 100ms. If the RTT is between 100ms and 200ms, the user can
> access the WorkSpace, but performance is affected. If the RTT is
> between 200ms and 375ms, the performance is degraded. **If the RTT
> exceeds 375ms, the WorkSpaces client connection is terminated.**

> For the best performance for WorkSpaces Streaming Protocol (WSP), the
> RTT from the client's network to the Region that the WorkSpaces are in
> should be less than 250ms. If the RTT is between 250ms and 400ms, the
> user can access the WorkSpace, but the performance is degraded.